# Electrical resistance of a metallic conductor in a gas

Tags: pressure, electrical-resistance, conductors

A long time ago I learned that the electrical resistance of a metallic conductor, when surrounded by a gas, varies with the pressure of said gas.
• What is the name (if any) of the law involved?
• Does the resistance increase or decrease with an increase in gas pressure?
• What is the reason for this?
TIA!

Comment: The only reference I've been able to find thus far is an article at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032591004000270 which details the influence of packing pressure on the electrical conductivity of compressed metal powders. For bulk metals like copper, pressure deviations above or below atmospheric pressure are probably unlikely to cause significant changes in electrical conductivity, although perhaps someone with more experience can say otherwise.